# Error 1009: Cannot access a proprty...null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have a .fla file that runs .swf movies on top of it based on user selection. I have several simple .swf movies that do not have any class files, just code on the timeline, and a .swf movie that has a large class file and some code on the timeline.

The simple .swf movies load and work fine, but the movie with a class does not load and comes up with Error 1009:...... at it's constructor.

The movie works fine when I run it by itself.

Comment: Can you paste code from the simple.swf?

Comment: A NPE (Null Pointer Exception) is thrown when a property or method is accessed on a null object.  Something like var myObject:Object = null; then myObject.anything will result in a null pointer exception.  Check the line referenced by the error for any "dereferencing" or use of the "dot operator" some var using that must be null for you to get an NPE, if the error doesn't point to a line in your code you may need to look in the stack trace to see what methods are called to get to the point of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably The stage of the loaded Movie is null.
Check if you try to use stage in Loaded Movie Constructor.